# Is it normal that LTO breaks code and how to avoid it?

Tags: c++, optimization, arduino, lto

I am developing a sound-generating program for an Attiny85 uC using Arduino IDE and [AttinyCore](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore) and stumbled across a problem I've never encountered before.

The timers initialization turns on two timers, Timer0 and Timer1. First one is used for the PWM output, the second one is used to time sample-rate interrupt. In short, this gives me two bytes, OCR0A and OCR0B, by changing which I can output sound, and an interrupt that is called at approx. 15kHz. Everything is done in a single file: setup() initializes timers, loop() renders the sound into sample1 and sample2, and ISR outputs the sound to OCR0A and OCR0B.

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include "Arduino.h"

#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/io.h>


uint8_t sample1 = 0, sample2 = 0;
uint16_t phase1 = 0, phase2 = 0;


void setup() {
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH); // Immedeately turn on this pull-up resistor for the reset pin
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT); // Two outputs
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  cli();
  // Turn on PLL and wait while it stabilizes
  bitSet(PLLCSR, PLLE);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  while(!bitRead(PLLCSR, PLOCK));
  bitSet(PLLCSR, PCKE);
  bitSet(PLLCSR, LSM);  //low speed mode, PLL @ 32MHz.

  //Set up the TIM0 timer
  TCCR0A = bit(WGM00) | bit(WGM01); //Mode: 011, fast PWM. IMHO regular CTC PWM is superior
  TCCR0B = 0; //WGM02 is zero
  TCCR0A |= bit(COM0A1); // Channel A: Non-inverting PWM mode (10)
  TCCR0A |= bit(COM0B1); // Channel B: Non-inverting PWM mode (10)
  bitSet(TCCR0B, CS00); // Timer frequency: CLKio/1 = 8MHz

  //Set up the TIM1 timer
  TCCR1 = 0; TCNT1 = 0; // Stop and clear the timer
  GTCCR = bit(PSR1); //Reset the timer
  OCR1A = 255; OCR1C = 255;
  TIMSK = bit(OCIE1A); // Interrupt enable
  TCCR1 = bit(CTC1) | bit(CS12);  //Clock: PLL Clock / 8 = 32MHz / 8 = 4 MHz = CPU Clock / 2
                                  //Final Timer1 config: reset on OCR1C compare
                                  //Interrupt on OCR1A compare
                                  //Frequency: 4MHz / 256 = 15625 Hz
  sei();
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
  OCR0A = sample1;
  OCR0B = sample2;

  //Internal oscillators 1, 2
  phase1 += 3*255;
  phase2 += 3*400;
}


void loop() {
  sample1 = phase1 >> 8;
  sample2 = phase2 >> 8;
}
```

Making phase1, phase2, sample1, sample2 volatile helps, but my question is - why?

The problem is that using LTO, -Os this code does not work. It can be fixed by either moving the calculation to the interrupt, or assigning calculation result straight to OCR0A and OCR0B bytes in synthesis() function, however, it is not the behaviour I desire since I want to keep the interrupt as short as possible.

But, either with -O0 (optimization turned off completely), or with LTO disabled this codes does work, but flash size in increased significantly (2.3kb with -O0, 700B with -Os, LTO disable, 504b with LTO enabled).

I could turn off LTO, but it seems like a dirty hack to me. My questions are:

1. Is it a dirty hack to disable LTO?
2. Is it normal for an optimizer to change behaviour so drastically? Why does it work without LTO?
3. Why exactly do I need to make these variables volatile and how to determine whether I need to make variables volatile (other than simple trial-and-error or simply making them all volatile?)
4. What else can I do besides changing optimizer settings and making something volatile?
5. Could it be a coding style issue?
6. Any advice on how to write code that optimizer does not break?

Comment: It's possible that the small flash size with LTO is a result of the linker entirely omitting parts of your code that it incorrectly thinks are unused, so you probably shouldn't assume there is a solution that will attain those sizes.

Comment: Does your platform really allow you to do things like this? How does it know not to optimize the accesses to `sample1` and `sample2` in `synthesis` into a register access or something other than looking where the interrupt routine stores them? Surely it must require you to do something to let it know what's going on. Most platforms require some kind of tag or special type for the shared variables.

Comment: I think that `sample1, sample2` have to be `volatile` at minimum.  Why it doesn't work after that is another question.  How do you install the ISR?  I wonder if the linker doesn't see that and therefore thinks the ISR is unused.

Comment: Whenever optimizers change behavior of your program unexpectedly, chances are, your code has some sort of undefined behavior. Unfortunately, the sample you have provided doesn't have enough information - we'd need [mcve].

Comment: 1. The -flto is relatively new, it's not usually enabled by default. 2. yes and no, size, speed alters, code is usually working (if there are not some race conditions or optimized out pieces) 3. The volatile is a MUST here. 4. depends on coding style, for example not making volatile variables used both in main code and inside of interrupts. 5. in MCU development you won't use anytning else than -Os and -flto is optional

Comment: The unguarded concurrent use of `sample1`, `sample2` causes undefined behaviour in standard C++ so the compiler would be within its rights to make a mess of the optimization